# How to pipe forward a ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipe

I would like to use a custom function defined on a ggplot object with `magrittr`'s pipe. However, I cannot pipe a ggplot object into this function.

Here is a simple example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

my_plot_function <- function(plot) {
    plot + geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed')
}

data(mtcars)
p <- mtcars %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, wt))
my_plot_function(p)
```

It would be great if I could use `my_plot_function()` within the chain as follows:

```r
mtcars %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) %>%
    my_plot_function()
```

However, it gives an error as only the layer is passed to `my_plot_function()` instead of the plot itself. How could I pass the plot with the pipe?

Comment: You can’t change operator precedence in R so the only way to make this work is to put the ggplotting stuff between the `%>%`s in parentheses. That’s probably not what you want, though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You mean `mtcars %>% (ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, wt))) %>% my_plot_function()`? It does not seem to work.

Comment: I meant `(mtcars %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, wt))) %>% my_plot_function()` (which works) but the description in my first comment was wrong, and would imply the code you wrote.

Comment: @Konrad you can't change operator precedence but you can use operators that have the right precedence, by defining `-.gg` or overriding `+.gg`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes of course. But defining a new operator doesn’t exactly make the code intuitive to understand, and overriding `+.gg` with different semantics would be even worse, because it actively does something different from what’s expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to define a function that does not expect a plot object and just add it as is usual in `ggplot`.

```
my_plot_function <- function() {
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed')
}


mtcars %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) + my_plot_function()
```

Comment: Oh, I did not expect the solution to be so simple :)

Comment: You can even have multiple geom's from my_plot() by returning a list of geom or other ggplot functions.

Answer (score 7):

For one argument functions such as the one you proposed you can use the following hack by defining `-.gg` :

```
`-.gg` <- function(e1, e2) e2(e1)

my_plot_function <- function(plot) {
  plot + geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed')
}

mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) -
  my_plot_function
```

*draws chart*

---

I use this trick a lot to use `ggplotly` :

```
library(plotly)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) -
  ggplotly
```

*draws an interractive chart*

---

or to plot intermediate charts

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) -
  plot +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

*draws 2 charts*

---

For a multi argument function you can use `purrr::partial` :

```
my_plot_function2 <- function(plot, msg) {
  print(msg)
  plot + geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed')
}

library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) -
  partial(my_plot_function2, msg="hello")
# [1] "hello"
```

*... and draws chart*

---

Define a function on the fly, in this example to edit the data of the plot :

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) -
  as_mapper(~{.$data <- head(.$data);.})
```

*draws chart with 6 points*

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to wrap the entire chain in `()` as a comment suggested. Here is an example where the template of the accepted answer fails:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

my_plot_function <- function() {
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 20, linetype = 'dotted')
}
my_plot_function2 <- function(plot) {
    plot + geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 20, linetype = 'dotted')
}
data(mtcars)
```

The following will throw an error:

```
mtcars %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) + my_plot_function()
```

The following will work:

```
(mtcars %>%
    ggplot() + geom_point(aes(mpg, wt))) %>%
    my_plot_function2()
```

If you want to keep the data chaining separated, you could use an anonymous function around the ggplot() call:

```
mtcars %>%
    (function(dat) ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(mpg, wt))) %>%
    my_plot_function2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do need a function that must have arguments, then `wrapr`'s dot arrow pipe `%.>%` works perfectly as a replacement to `+`. Then you must just specify `.` as the input to your function.

[Documentation](https://winvector.github.io/wrapr/reference/dot_arrow.html)

---

Another, presumably easier alternative, is to return a list in the function. Example:

```
foo <- function() {
  Out <- list(
    theme(
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_line(colour="black"),
    expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0),
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)),
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
  )

  return(Out)
}
```

The usefulness of the latter alternative is that it becomes much easier to standardize your graphics, for instance with a custom-made theme that also requires some changes to non-theme functions (exemplified above)